# Debian 9 with intel i7-8700

Tags: debian, cpu

Will it be any issues (excluding uhd 630 graphics kernel parameter: `i915.alpha_support`) while installing debian stretch (kernel 4.9) on machine with Intel 8th i7-8700 ?

Comment: Do you have the Intel i7-8700 or are you thinking of getting it? If you have it you might try the live+non-free disk to try it. https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/

Comment: @arochester I am going to buy and I am wondering if debian stretch will install on it ,or I need newer kernel than 4.9 ?

Comment: Debian Testing (Buster) rather than Stable? https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=8700k-linux-distros&num=1

Comment: @arochester yes I saw this but any single word that it won't boot with 4.9 kernel (with stretch)

Comment: You could try Stretch. If it doesn't work then go to Buster. Testing is not as unstable as many people think.

Comment: @arochester yes I am going to try.

Comment: Perhaps not useful, but I'm running i7-8700K fine with Arch Linux (kernel 4.15.6-1-ARCH). LTS kernel works fine too (4.14.22-1). So if Debian fails, you can always(?) move to Arch.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with computer of my collegues. He has new computer with this processor and he needs debian. Debian 9 has in backports repository kernel of 4.13. But, am I able to install from backports repository to stable version with 4.9 kernel on this processor, if 4.9 kernel donť function on it.

Comment: You need debian buster (10). I couldn't launch GPU acceleration in stretch even with i915.aplha_support kernel parameter with 4.13 kernel. Probably something else needed to be upgraded on stretch to work.

Answer (score 0):

It will work with Linux Kernel 4.9 (Debian 9 Stable)but not completely, this is what happened for me (Intel i7-8700 + Motherboard Asus TUF Gaming)

- the sound is NOT recognized via HDMI (only via my headphones)
- resolution of the screen is limited to 3 choices

*** What works ***
From Linux Kernel 4.13 because the GPU needs it. (Source: https://www.golem.de/news/core-i7-8700k-und-core-i5-8400-im-test-ein-sechser-von-intel-1710-130390-5.html

*** What works for me** : I installed Linux Kernel 4.15 via UKUU (Ubuntu Kernel Update Utility) (source: http://www.teejeetech.in/p/ukuu-kernel-upgrade-utility.html)
 **UKUU is an open source tool *** (Source:https://alternativeto.net/software/ukuu-kernel-upgrade-utility/)

Enjoy !